# Rewrite a url with multiple parameters

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I'm working on a php project which I'm finding it hard to rewrite a url with multiple parameters

```
RewriteRule ^search/([0-9]+) search/search.php?profile_id=$1&class=$2&tutor=$3
```

Comment: You need 3 capturing groups: `^search/([0-9]+)/([^/.]+)/(.*?)$`

Comment: thanks its working but makes page losses some source files (css) breaking the structure of the page. currently my url looks like this http://localhost/mysite/user/search/1/6/maxwell

Answer (score 0):

To use `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, you need to use 3 capturing groups. So change your RewriteURL pattern to something like this:

```
^search/([0-9]+)/([^/.]+)/(.*?)$
```

But this will break your relative paths. Better use,

```
<base href='/'>
```

Read [this article](http://smal.me.pn/base-href) to know more about using base tag